# box-shadow обрезается если у элемента списка overflow:scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

Если ограничена высота списка и установлено `overflow:scroll`, тень обрезается снизу и сверху всего списка и у каждого элемента справа и слева
https://codepen.io/JuliaGinkul/pen/XWEQBGP

```css
.Container {
  position: relative;
}

.Select {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% + 10px);
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  min-width: 160px;
  width: 249px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: 1;
}

.Menu {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  border-radius: 4.44px;
  margin: 0;
  max-height: 128px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.Item {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: grey;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.Item:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.Item:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px blue;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 4.44px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div class="Select">
    <ul class="Menu">
      <li class="Item">пункт 1</li>
      <li class="Item">пункт 2</li>
      <li class="Item">пункт 3</li>
      <li class="Item">пункт 4</li>
      <li class="Item">пункт 5</li>
      <li class="Item">пункт 6</li>
      <li class="Item">пункт 7</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: задайте паддинги для списка равные ширине тени

Answer (score 0):

`.Menu` --> `padding: 3px;`, т.к `box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px blue;`

Пример

```css
.Container {
  position: relative;
}

.Select {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% + 10px);
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  min-width: 160px;
  width: 249px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: 1;
}

.Menu {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  border-radius: 4.44px;
  margin: 0;
  max-height: 128px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 3px;
}

.Item {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: grey;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.Item+.Item::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: calc(100% + 6px);
  margin-left: -3px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.Item:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.Item::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -1px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px blue;
  border-radius: 2px;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s ease;
}

.Item:hover {
  color: #000;
}

.Item:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div class="Select">
    <ul class="Menu">
      <li class="Item">пункт 1</li>
      <li class="Item">пункт 2</li>
      <li class="Item">пункт 3</li>
      <li class="Item">пункт 4</li>
      <li class="Item">пункт 5</li>
      <li class="Item">пункт 6</li>
      <li class="Item">пункт 7</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: не совсем то, что требуется, тень должна выступать за края Menu, плюс отодвигается нижний бордер справа и слева

Answer (score 0):

так и должно быть. Overflow, который обрезает по размеру элемента (hidden/scroll/auto) обрежет и тень.

вариант 1 - изображать что-то похожее, городя жуть на css и js. желаемый вами результат точно стоит этих извращений?

вариант 2 - сделать паддинги LI-шкам, а тени применять к внутреннему элементу:

```css
.Container {
  position: relative;
}

.Select {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% + 10px);
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  min-width: 160px;
  width: 249px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  z-index: 1;
}

.Menu {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  border-radius: 4.44px;
  margin: 0;
  max-height: 128px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.Item {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: grey;
  padding: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.Item div {
  padding: 7px 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
}

.Item:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.Item:hover div {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px blue;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 4.44px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div class="Select">
    <ul class="Menu">
      <li class="Item">
        <div>пункт 1</div>
      </li>
      <li class="Item">
        <div>пункт 2</div>
      </li>
      <li class="Item">
        <div>пункт 3</div>
      </li>
      <li class="Item">
        <div>пункт 4</div>
      </li>
      <li class="Item">
        <div>пункт 5</div>
      </li>
      <li class="Item">
        <div>пункт 6</div>
      </li>
      <li class="Item">
        <div>пункт 7</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```